# VSCode find references of double wrapped es6 modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, visual-studio-code

I was wondering if there is a good way to find all references of a double wrapped module in vs code. To be more specific, if I look for all references (shift + alt + F12) of a file exported like that:

`export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CustomModal);`

VSCode returns the expected result. However, if the module is exported like this

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(injectIntl(Dialog));
```

VScode only finds references in the current file. Is there a way to find all the references without going through the search function?

Comment: For just finding it? Always with connect? On one line? Do you plan to do a replace on anything?

Comment: Yes just for finding it. I basically want to know, who is importing the module (import Dialog from './Dialog';)